# mkdir permission denied error when running Browser based test

Tags: 8, testing

I've wrote a browser based test for the contributed module, code can be seen [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/readonlymode/tree/tests/src/Functional/ReadonlymodeTest.php?id=22ed5dc), when I run test in terminal I get following error

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit   --configuration /home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/core/phpunit.xml --filter "/::testReadOnlyModeEnabled( .*)?$/" Drupal\Tests\readonlymode\Functional\ReadOnlyModeTest /home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/modules/porting/readonlymode/tests/src/Functional/ReadonlymodeTest.php -v
PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 7.1.10 with Xdebug 2.5.5
Configuration:  /home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/core/phpunit.xml

Testing Drupal\Tests\readonlymode\Functional\ReadOnlyModeTest
E

Time: 2 minutes, Memory: 6.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Drupal\Tests\readonlymode\Functional\ReadOnlyModeTest::testReadOnlyModeEnabled
Exception: User warning: mkdir(): Permission Denied
Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->createDirectory()() (Line: 173)


/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/HttpClientMiddleware/TestHttpClientMiddleware.php:44
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:203
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:156
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php:47
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:246
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:223
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:267
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:225
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:62
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:131
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/fabpot/goutte/Goutte/Client.php:155
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:315
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/behat/mink-browserkit-driver/src/BrowserKitDriver.php:144
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/vendor/behat/mink/src/Session.php:148
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:333
/home/sharique/Projects/drupal/d8/d8contrib/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:472

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
```

Same error when running from PhpStorm

Comment: Have you confirmed the user executing that test has permissions to write to the folder it's complaining about?

Comment: I get this a lot too, and I think I have a question on here about it but can’t find it at the moment.

Comment: yes, the user permissions are  correct.

Comment: The operating system doesn't really seem to agree with you -  what folder is it trying to create a folder in, who owns that folder, what mode does it and its content have, and what user executes the test script?

Comment: I think it is trying to create folder in "sites/simpletest/",
User is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the *Permission problems* section of [Running PHPUnit tests](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/running-phpunit-tests) can help you:

> Note: functional tests have to be invoked with a user in the same group as the web server user. You can either configure Apache (or nginx) to run as your own system user or run tests as a privileged user instead.
>
> To develop locally, a straightforward - but also less secure - approach is to run tests as your own system user. To achieve that, change the default Apache user to run as your system user. Typically, you'd need to modify `/etc/apache2/envvars` on Linux or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` on Mac.
>
> Example for Linux:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=<your-user>
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=<your-group>
```

> If the default user is e.g. `www-data`, the above functional tests will have to be invoked with `sudo` instead:

```
export SIMPLETEST_DB='mysql://root@localhost/dev_d8'
export SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL='http://d8.dev'
sudo -u www-data -E ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c core --testsuite functional
sudo -u www-data -E ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c core --testsuite functional-javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer didn't help me. I had the simpletests folder with `777` permissions. I ran the tests as `root`, or as `www-data`. It didn't matter. The only fix that worked for me was found at the end of `core/tests/README.md`:

> If you have permission problems accessing files after running tests,
> try putting
>
> ```
> $settings['file_chmod_directory'] = 02775;
> ```
>
> in your
> settings.php or local.settings.php file.

That fixed it for me, finally. Then, for example, I can run

```bash
/var/www/html$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c core/phpunit.xml core/path/to/test/some/file.php
```

Since it's for running tests in a local development environment set up inside a Docker image, the most important thing is getting it all to run successfully, and this is what got it to work for me.